# What's the best database/data strategy to build up a forum using Java Servlet/JSP/JSF and combining Ajax?

Tags: jsp, jsf, forum

Frequently for standard J2EE projects I use directly SQL constructs or ORM framework to manage data into forms and so on, but of course enterprise environments don't bother much about n-users access performances at the same time.

So what could it be the most performance suited strategy for an user forum of up 50 users and more?

Have you any advice?

1) In my opinion I must keep a fast access index of all front/last messages at data level, but I am in doubt for using plain text file(s) or a database table?

2) Visually my idea is to build up all on a top of a message list linked only to the "fast access index", and then using Ajax to get message details and content, so I can divide the application flows into two separate channels, one aimed to  serve fast content and the other to serve complex data (content message, user details and so on).

Important notice:

the forum application must fits well on any "poor" data and Java environment, please do not phpize my question ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a read on Hibernate and the second-level cache. You could cache all of your "fast access" stuff so the DB is not hit until more detail is requested about an entry.